# 3 species pride, could it work?

Tags: fauna, interspecies-relations

1 of my stories involves a pride. But not just any old lion pride. No, my story involves a pride with 3 different big cat species. I don't know if I should put character histories here or whether that would make it better for Writers but here I go.

**Duma, the cheetah**

Duma was 1 of a litter of 4 cheetah cubs. He was the odd one of the bunch. He had a nomadic lioness that he spent more and more time with as he got older. Once he was 2 years old, he set off to find a male lion to partner with.

**Anapumua Moto, the male lion**

Anapumua Moto was born in a regular lion pride. Duma secretly watched him without any lions knowing he was there. Once he was 2 years old, he ran for his life. This is when Duma partnered with him. Despite the cheetah chirp being very different from a lion roar, they understand each other.

**Bella, the leopard**

Bella has encountered lions lots of times but only once has it ended in friendship. That just happened to be with Anapumua Moto. She is very willing to help, even tackling a zebra to help her lion friend. At first Duma was scared but Duma became friends with her too.

**Nala, the nomadic lioness**

Nala is the nomadic lioness that Duma remembers being with as a cub. It is also the first nomadic lioness that joins Anapumua Moto's pride.

**Kanya, the pregnant, nomadic lioness**

Kanya is the second lioness to join Anapumua Moto's pride. She also happens to be Nala's lioness friend. But Kanya never told Nala that she was pregnant and now she is visibly pregnant.

So anyway, is a pride like this with 2 lionesses, 1 male lion, 1 cheetah for spotting enemies and prey, and 1 leopard to help when prey is scarce, plausible for my story or is there something in the character histories that would prevent this from happening?

Comment: From your story, seems like you are writing for non-serious reading. Why would you worry so much about realism?

Comment: Well, it isn't so much that I would worry about realism(in fact, even in my more sci fi stories, there are unrealistic elements). But if it is plausible scientifically(even though it hasn't happened for real yet), that makes it even better in my opinion for a story that people of all ages might want to read.

Comment: The approach in checking the plausibility of this pride makes sense. I remember a children's fantasy who wrote a book about merpeople. She carefully researched the biology of the marine mammals that also appeared in her story. It may have been a fantasy, but she wanted her science to be right.

Comment: The plausibility of your pride depends on the social behaviour and bonding relationships of the different species of cats. Domesticated animals have become domesticated because their social behaviour fits with the social behaviour of humans. Something similar will need to happen with your cats. A comment only. I don't have the expertise to go further.

Comment: Animal don't feel full of themselves the way we do at least not loudly inside the head.

Comment: There are four off-topic close votes for this question and not one comment helping the OP understand the problem.  Frankly, I don't see the problem myself.  How is working through the basic science of animal interrelations, especially in what would be deemed an "alternate reality" of Earth, NOT be worldbuilding?

Comment: @JBH right. *"I don't know if I should put character histories here"* The story is put here just for "example" of what the OP has in mind now. The question "Is multi-species cat pride plausible?" is narrow enough, and is not story based.

Answer (score 5):

Scientifically plausible? **Yes**

A cat mother can raise different species offsprings. Here's some:

- Youtube: [Lioness adopt leopard cub.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf5OiiZ-OzA)
- Youtube: [Lioness helps tigress to raise cubs.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNkFMMAjNm4)
- [Lion nursing leopard cub.](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2017/07/leopards-lions-cubs-nursing-tanzania/)

There's even a weirder party of [Bear, Lion, and Tiger](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/bear-lion-tiger-friends_us_56d8c354e4b0ffe6f8e8bb11).

> “**Before they reach sexual maturity,** a lot of times animals will form unique bonds with members of other species,” she told BBC, explaining that animals typically grow apart as they get older. “What was surprising is how they kept that bond, that family unit well into adulthood.”

[image: Bear, Lion, and Tiger]

**Note:** Remember that there's no report of adult cats forming a pride in the wild, so your pride is better to have a tightly bonded childhood, or they are escapees from a stressful captivity. Adult species may work together and form bonds as a response from external mutual threat.

Answer (score 3):

So ... here's the thing.

In the wild, lions like to slap around the smaller cats and steal their lunch.  You can see details here (http://channel.nationalgeographic.com/wild/big-cat-week/episodes/cat-wars-lion-vs-cheetah1/) and it ain't pretty.

Honestly, you'd have better luck with the herbivores.  Turns out wildebeest, zebras, und so weiter do hang around together.  They don't exactly ... socialize, but they do rely one one another's differing sensory skills to detect predators.

Since these are not your typical cats -- they have names and such -- you may be able to make it work, at the expense of some realism.  You might at least make some explanation as to how they came to get along (and maybe it took them awhile to learn come to a modus vivendi).

If you can smooth this out, then your mixed pride will be pretty neat; the different cat species have different strengths and will be able to help each other in ways that single-kind prides cannot.